# Why Code is called 2 times ? Java Android Threads Handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to run some code piece when progressbar status reaches 100.(in this case diggingStatus)
But for some reason Log.d code is called 2 times not 1 time.I guess my if(diggingStatus==100) condition is in wrong place.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    private Handler diggingHandler = new Handler();

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(diggingStatus < 100){
                            // Update the progress status
                            diggingStatus +=1;

                            try{
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // Update the progress bar
                            diggingHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    diggingbar.setProgress(diggingStatus);
                                    if(diggingStatus==100){
    //Run this code when progress is completed.
    Log.d("i got called","i got called "); //Why this is called 2 times? 


                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }




                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: try to use AsyncTask, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you handling a async message, when both execute the variable diggingStatus already is 100.

You have to send the ammount of progress to the handler as well such:

```
                        final int progress = diggingStatus; //get only the current
                        // Update the progress bar
                        diggingHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                diggingbar.setProgress(progress);
                                if(progress==100)
                                     Log.d("i got called","i got called ");
                            }
                        });
```